# Build an array in JavaScript to fill jsTree

Tags: javascript, json, jstree

I am trying to build a tree of files (for a web application) by using JsTree.

I have different levels:

**level 1:** `dimension`

**level 2:** `hierarchie` (`dimension`'s child)

**level 3:** `niveau, Ordre_niveau = 1` (`hierarchie`'s child)

**level n:** `niveau, Ordre_niveau = n` (`niveau ordre (n-1)`'s child)

I succeed in filling `dimension` and `hierarchie`, but all my `niveau` are at the same level because the information of `ordre` is in the same object as the information of `niveau`.

Here is my code:

```
var jsTreeData = [];
//"dimensions"
for (var i = 0; i < dimension.length; i++) {
  jsTreeData.push({
    'text': dimension[i].dimension_Nom_dimension,
    'type': 'dimension',
    'data': dimension[i],
    'children': []
  });

  //"hiérarchies"
  var x = -1;
  for (var j = 0; j < hierarchie.length; j++) {
    if (hierarchie[j].dimension_Dimension_id == jsTreeData[i].data.dimension_Dimension_id) {
      jsTreeData[i].children.push({
        'text': hierarchie[j].hierarchie_Nom_hierarchie,
        'type': 'hierarchie',
        'data': hierarchie[j],
        'children': []
      });
      x = x + 1;
      //"niveaux"        
      for (var k = 0; k < niveau.length && x < (jsTreeData[i].children.length); k++) {
        for (var l = 0; l < niveau.length && x < (jsTreeData[i].children.length); l++) {

          if (niveau[k].hierarchie_Hierarchie_id == jsTreeData[i].children[x].data.hierarchie_Hierarchie_id && niveau[k].niveau_Niveau_id == niveau[l].niveau_Niveau_parent_id && niveau[k].niveau_Ordre_niveau == 1 && niveau[l].niveau_Ordre_niveau == 2) {
            jsTreeData[i].children[x].children.push({
              'text': niveau[k].niveau_Nom_niveau,
              'type': 'niveau',
              'data': niveau[k],
              'children': ({
                jsTreeData: ({
                  'text': niveau[l].niveau_Nom_niveau,
                  'type': 'niveau',
                  'data': niveau[l]
                })
              })
            });
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The result is that the Jstree display all the `dimension`, all the `hierarchie` but only the `niveau, Ordre_niveau = 1` and not the `niveau, Ordre_niveau = 2`, etc.

It is like the property `children` of Jstree doesn't work.

Comment: Not sure is this will help, but there are 2 ways you can pass nodes to JsTree. One is with children that you are using; other is the alternative format as on this url https://www.jstree.com/docs/json/. You'll have to provide the id and parent yourself, and thus might work.

Comment: I tried but every time I have this error: "Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined " in the JsTree code:                                                                   // 2) populate children (foreach)
for(i = 0, j = dat.length; i < j; i++) {                         m[dat[i].parent.toString()].children.push(dat[i].id.toString());
// populate parent.children_d
p.children_d.push(dat[i].id.toString());
      })                                                                    Do you know why?

Comment: Ok I saw what was the problem. If there is only one data with "undefined" parent and there is no code for this exception, the JsTree send the error.

Comment: This problem occurs, when the object (or property) is either undefined or null. In the code either parent or id is undefined. Is the node with error is your root node, in that case u still need to provide the parent (as '#').

Answer (score -2):

I don't understand you question, but you can use the easiest way to fix and debugging: `console.log('Some label', variable);` Use it in every place where you have the `if ... else` or `for (i =0, ...)` or in other problem for you places. It help you find errors or mistakes.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I know, this is very unclear but your tip might help.